# Strange layout rendering created with xml in andoid

Tags: java, android

I want to arrange buttons evenly on the layout using styles to make my code simple. So why buttons have different distance between each other and ViewGroup? Am I right that attributes defined in the xml file overrides style's attributes?

// xml code for the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            style="@style/style1"
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:text="button1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b2" />

    <Button
            style="@style/style1"
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:text="button2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b3" />

    <Button
            style="@style/style1"
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:text="button3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b2"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

// used style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="style1">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="layout_constraintTop_toTopOf">parent</item>
        <item name="layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf">parent</item>
        <item name="layout_constraintRight_toRightOf">parent</item>
        <item name="layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf">parent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the three buttons have in common is `layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf` and `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf`.

So in style you will only define these two attributes of `layout_constraint`.

**STYLE**

```
<style name="style1" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/teal_200</item>

    <!--  layout_constraint attributes  -->
    <item name="layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintStart_toStartOf">parent</item>
</style>
```

**`your_activity.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".YourActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        style="@style/style1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b2"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        style="@style/style1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b3"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        style="@style/style1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

With this code, AndroidStudio will point out an error in the xml file, after all the `ConstraintLayout` was not made to define its attributes from style. But your app will run normally.
Don't forget to put your your `ActivityClass` in `tools:context=".ActivityClass"`.

Tip: when you want to set a text size in any android xml, you should use "`sp`" instead of "`dp`".

**Example**

Incorrect:

```
<item name="android:textSize">10dp</item>
```

Correct

```
<item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
```

Comment: Can I override any attributes defined in style xml file ?